# angular8 component is not displaying it's html?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have an `angular8` application in which i have a module named 'shop' with the following directory structure :

[image]

here is my `shop.module.ts` `declarations`, `imports`, `providers`

```
declarations: [
HomePartialComponent,
ProductsComponent,
ProductComponent,
ProductDetailsComponent,
ProductDialogComponent,
ProductLeftSidebarComponent,
ProductVerticalComponent,
ProductCarouselTwoComponent,
PriceComponent,
ShopComponent,
BrandsComponent,
CategoriesComponent,
PopularProductsComponent,
ProductZoomComponent,
MainCarouselComponent
],

imports: [
CommonModule,
SharedModule,
FormsModule, 
SwiperModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
FlexLayoutModule,
NgxPaginationModule,
NgxImageZoomModule.forRoot()
],

providers : [ProductService,CartService,SidebarMenuService]
```

And here is my `shop.component.html` code in which i am calling `home-partial` component

[image]

but my `home-partial` component is not showing it's html. It's showing in inspect element of `shop.component.html` like this

[image]

Here is `home-partial` componen.html code

```html
<div class="carousel-2">
    <div class="container ctn-box">
        <div class="" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayout.xs="column">
            <div class="slider-categories" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="25" fxFlex.md="40">
                <div class="categories-wrap">
                    <div class="title"> TOP CATEGORIES</div>
                    <app-categories></app-categories>
                    <div class="btn-sale">
                        <button mat-raised-button color="primary">USE THE DISCOUNT - 60% OFF</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-2-wrapper" fxLayout.sm="column" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="75" fxFlex.md="60" fxFlex.sm="100">
                <app-main-carousel [slides]="slides"></app-main-carousel>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="home-2-wrap">
    <div class="info-bar2-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div fxLayout="row wrap" class="info-bar">
                <div class="card-wrap" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="25" fxFlex.gt-xs="50">
                    <mat-card class="light-block" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-xlg  m-0">card_giftcard</mat-icon>
                        <div class="content">
                            <p>BONUS PLUS</p>
                            <span class="text-muted m-0">Get a bonus plus for buying more that three products</span>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
                <div class="card-wrap" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="25" fxFlex.gt-xs="50">
                    <mat-card class="light-block" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-xlg  m-0">local_shipping</mat-icon>
                        <div class="content">
                            <p>FREE SHIPPING</p>
                            <span class="text-muted m-0">Free shipping on all orders over $99</span>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
                <div class="card-wrap" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="25" fxFlex.gt-xs="50">
                    <mat-card class="light-block" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-xlg m-0">monetization_on</mat-icon>
                        <div class="content">
                            <p>MONEY BACK GUARANTEE</p>
                            <span class="text-muted m-0">100% money back guarantee</span>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
                <div class="card-wrap" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="25" fxFlex.gt-xs="50">
                    <mat-card class="light-block" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-xlg m-0">history</mat-icon>
                        <div class="content">
                            <p>ONLINE SUPPORT 24/7</p>
                            <span class="text-muted m-0">Call us: 02 3555 65454 55</span>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="products sec-padding">
        <div class="container">
            <mat-tab-group>

                <mat-tab label="FEATURED PRODUCTS">

                    <app-product-carousel-two [product]="products | slice:0:5"></app-product-carousel-two>


                </mat-tab>

                <mat-tab label="LATEST PRODUCTS">

                    <app-product-carousel-two [product]="products | slice:5:13"></app-product-carousel-two>

                </mat-tab>

                <mat-tab label="ON SALE PRODUCTS">

                    <app-product-carousel-two [product]="products | slice:13:22"></app-product-carousel-two>

                </mat-tab>

            </mat-tab-group>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="banners-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <app-banners [banners]="banners"></app-banners>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="products-vertical-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <app-product-vertical [products]="products"></app-product-vertical>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the `shop.component.ts` code

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from 'src/app/modals/product.model';
import { CartItem } from 'src/app/modals/cart-item';
import { ProductService } from './../../../../services/product.service';
import { CartService } from './../../../../services/cart.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-partial',
  templateUrl: './home-partial.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-partial.component.sass']
})


export class HomePartialComponent implements OnInit {


  products: Product[];
  public banners = [];

  shoppingCartItems: CartItem[] = [];
  wishlistItems  :   Product[] = [];

  public featuredProducts: Array<Product>;
  public onSaleProducts: Array<Product>;
  public topRatedProducts: Array<Product>;
  public newArrivalsProducts: Array<Product>;

  public slides = [
    { title: 'Huge sale', subtitle: 'Up to 70%', image: 'assets/images/carousel/banner1.jpg' },
    { title: 'Biggest discount', subtitle: 'Check the promotion', image: 'assets/images/carousel/banner2.jpg' },
    { title: 'Biggest sale', subtitle: 'Dont miss it', image: 'assets/images/carousel/banner3.jpg' },
    { title: 'Our best products', subtitle: 'Special selection', image: 'assets/images/carousel/banner4.jpg' },
    { title: 'Massive sale', subtitle: 'Only for today', image: 'assets/images/carousel/banner5.jpg' }
  ];

  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private cartService: CartService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cartService.getItems().subscribe(shoppingCartItems => this.shoppingCartItems = shoppingCartItems);
    this.productService.getProducts()
    .subscribe(
      (product: Product[]) => {
        this.products = product;
      }
    )
    this.productService.getBanners()
    .subscribe(
      data => this.banners = data
    );
  }

}
```

In `shop` component `header` and `footer` is displaying correctly but just 'home-partial' component is not showing it's html. Can any one guide me that how can i fix this issue?

Comment: So the problem is with the HomePartialComponent... but you didn't post any of its code.

Comment: @JBNizet i have updated my question please have a look of it.

Comment: Post code as text. Not as images. And look in the browser console for an error.

Comment: @JBNizet  i have updated my question and included the `home-partial` component html code. please see the updated question

Comment: Do you have any error in the browser console?

Comment: no. there is no error in console.

Comment: And what's the TypeScript code of the component?

Comment: @JBNizet see updated question. I have included my `home-partial.component.ts` code

Comment: Maybe you should create minial reproduce code in https://stackblitz.com

Comment: @JBNizet i can't because there are lots of folders in my sub folders. Can you come to my pc using `Team Viewer` ?

Comment: Remove everything that is irrelevant (or just create a new project containing only what is relevant) until you have something working (and then you'll know where the problem is), or a **minimal** example that you can share in a stackblitz.

Comment: all the folders are relevent because there are separate components which are using in `home-partial` component. Can you please come to my pc using team viewer?

Comment: No. Definitely not. And they're irrelevant because the problem is that nothing shows up, not even the static HTML contained in the template. So just replace the template by "hello", and you'll still have your issue, and all the other components will be irrelevant.

Comment: But i am customizing an angular theme so how can i integrate all the theme styles and services, widgets and all stuff into stackblitz, that's time consuming. I have created a `stackblitz` here with my `shop` module and `home-partial` code please see this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a6swa6

In shop component `header-component` and `footer` component is displaying correctly but only problem is with `home-partial` component.

Comment: You're missing the point. Your current problem is that the template of the home-partial component doesn't display. So find the cause of **that** problem, by eliminating everything that isn't relevant to that problem. Once you've found the cause and fixed that problem, you can move on to your next goal.